# Ajax refresh on fancybox close

Tags: php, sql, ajax, fancybox

I have the content of a div being generated like this...

```
<div class="messagecount">
<?php
$mesagecount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "messages WHERE message_to_user_ID = %d", $user_ID));
echo $messagecount;
?>
</div>
```

I am also using fancybox to popup a message, I have the callback set so that when I close the fancybox I can call a command, but now I want to be able to refresh the messagecount div without refreshing the page.

Can I do this using ajax in combination with the fancybox close callback?

Comment: of course you can, both your ajax call and fancybox (if you're using what i think you are) are actually ajax calls, easy-peasy... what have you tried?

Comment: Where is that information? The information that updates the message count div?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
First, assign to your div id "messagecount".
Then, put in the head section of your document the following code:

```
<script>
function ajaxRequest(){
 var activexmodes=["Msxml2.XMLHTTP", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"]
 if (window.ActiveXObject){
  for (var i=0; i<activexmodes.length; i++){
   try{
    return new ActiveXObject(activexmodes[i])
   }
   catch(e){
   }
  }
 }
 else if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  return new XMLHttpRequest()
 else
  return false
}
</script>
```

Now, create load.php and put into it:

```
<?php
$mesagecount = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . $wpdb->base_prefix . "messages WHERE message_to_user_ID = %d", $user_ID));
echo $messagecount;
?>
```

To reload the box, just put the following code after it:

```
<a href="#"  onclick="sending(); return false;">Reload</a>
<script>
    function sending(){
    document.getElementById("messagecount").innerHTML="Refreshing"
    var mypostrequest=new ajaxRequest()
    mypostrequest.onreadystatechange=function(){
     if (mypostrequest.readyState==4){
      if (mypostrequest.status==200 || window.location.href.indexOf("http")==-1){
       document.getElementById("messagecount").innerHTML=mypostrequest.responseText
      }
      else{
       document.getElementById("messagecount").innerHTML='Woops! An error occurred. Please check your Internet connection and try again.';
      }
     }
    }
    mypostrequest.open("GET", "load.php", true)
    mypostrequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    }
</script>
```